# How to get the location of playlists stored in android device

Tags: android, file, filepath, playlist

I'm developing an android app that backup the playlists from my device then restore it so I have to know where is the location of the playlist on the device to get it and backup it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to use `MediaStore.Audio.Playlists` for getting all details regarding playlist.

Find out more details [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.html).

Comment: I want the whole file so I can copy it and restore it.